# jQuery UI reload tab content in ASP.NET MVC 3 application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I'd like in an ASP.NET MVC 3 reload the tab content each tab I change tab, when I select the first tab (index = 0), I'd like reload the content. In the tab, it's a ASP.NET MVC partial View

I have this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#tabs').tabs();
    });
</script>

<div id="tabs"> 
    <ul> 
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">AAAA</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">BBBB</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabs-1"> 
        @Html.Partial("PartialViewA", Model)
    </div> 
    <div id="tabs-2"> 
        @Html.Partial("PartialViewB", Model)
    </div> 

<div>
```

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: here you go
view-source:http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/cookie.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [jQuery tabs demos](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax) it should be as simple as doing:

```
<div id="tabs"> 
    <ul> 
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("myActionA", "myController")">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("myActionB", "myController")">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

then in your controller:

```
public ActionResult MyActionA
{
    return Partial("PartialViewA");
}

public ActionResult MyActionB
{
    return Partial("PartialViewB");
}
```

Comment: +1 I want to be able to directly access Tab 2 by url. So if I say `www.myDomain.com/controler/Action#Tab2` then it should show tab2. How to achieve it in this way?

Comment: I've never used the jQuery tabs myself so I wouldn't really know, but I guess you could make the tab number an action method parameter, pass it to the view through the `ViewBag` or in the view model and switch to the corresponding tab with jQuery.

Comment: See jim's answer. That worked well. with `show` event instead of `select`

Answer (score 3):

here's a quick example, the IMPORTANT part is the `select: function(e, ui)` bit when you initialise the tabs as this overrides the default bahaviour and gives access to the tab click event:

```
<div id="menu" style=" background-color:White; width:950px; height:400px; float:left;">             
    <div id="tabContainer">
        <ul> 
            <li><a href="#tab0">Home</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#tab1">Products</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#tab2">Contact Us</a></li>                                               
        </ul>                    

        <div id="tab0"></div>    
        <div id="tab1"></div> 
        <div id="tab2"></div>       
    </div>          
</div> 

$(function() {
    var $tabs = $("#tabContainer").tabs({
        select: function(e, ui) {
            var thistab = ui;
            runMethod(thistab.index);
        }
    });
});

function runMethod(thistab) {
    selectedtab = thistab;
    switch (thistab) {
        case 1:
            getTab0Data();
            break;

        case 2:
            getTab1Data();
            break;

        case 3:
            getTab2Data();
            break;
    }
}
```

basically, the getTab*n*Data() function(s) run an ajax request that populates the appropriate div (i.e. tab0, tab1, tab2 etc) via a partialview result.

for jquery ajax, see:

[jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

hope this helps

Comment: BTW, I guess there might be some use of `$tabs` variable or it's just like that? Can you please throw some light on this.

Comment: Ismail - the $tabs variable can be used to access any of the prepopulated option variable that you may have initialised the tabs component with. i personally have never had cause to use them, but it's useful to have a handle on the instance for that purpose.

Comment: Great! Very happy to see your quick answer. Thanks very much Jim :-)

Comment: But, select event is not firing in the first request. Hence not loading the content whether I give request url as normal or suffixed with #tab1 :(. Why? Later when I click tab 2 or 3 then it loads properly.

Comment: Ismail - couldn't be certain without seeing full code. however, an easy fix is to include the partialview in the tab0 div. i.e <div id="tab0"><%Html.RenderPartial("MyViewforthisTab"); %></div> - just a thought to get you by for now...

Comment: Thanks @jim, `show` instead of `select` event worked nicely. :)

Comment: Ismail - nice one. i'll take a look at that myself ;) glad you found a simple generic fix.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this post:

http://dalldorf.com/blog/2011/03/jquery-ui-tabs-main-menu-1/

It may help you find a solution.

It explains how to use the jQuery UI Style Tabs look and feel but leaves you with more control about how the content gets rendered.

It avoids the caching and nesting of recursive calls to the layout...

Answer (score 1):

check the demos from [jQuery Tabs Ajax Demos](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax), just call your controller and return a partial view from it.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution wich is to deny caching the action method, and at the same time keep the tabs caching enabled so you don't lose any current input when switching tabs like this:

```
[OutputCaching(Location=OutputCacheLocation.None,NoStore=true)]
Public ActionResult YourMethod()...
```

Comment: [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]

Answer (score 0):

According to the the [jQuery UI site](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax) you can try to specify the cache option explicitly

e.g.

```
$(function () {
    $('#tabs').tabs({
        cache: false
    });
});
```

That will prevent the browser from caching the original ajax content, so when you revisit the tab it will reload its content.